# Constant product formula

Tags: tokens, uniswap

the way I understand the constant product formula is that if I provide 100% of the total liquidity on token launch (for example 1000 USDC for 1000 TOKEN => 1 Token = 1USDC) the price of the token could never go beneath 1USDC per Token.

Is that correct?
Would an additional burn per transaction affect that outcome?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can go below 1 USDC per token.

If you input 1000 of both (let's say they are asset X and Y), then in the beginning the ratio is 1:1. And the constant product formula is `X * Y = k` and in our case `1000 * 1000 = k`.

If someone wants to buy 400 of X, the `k` has to remain constant, so the buyer has to pay whatever it takes to keep the formula balanced, so `(1000 - 400) * Y = k`. Which can be written as `600 * Y = 1000 * 1000` (see formula above). Here you solve `Y` and you'll find out how much of Y he has to input to buy 400 of X.

The next purchase of X is again even more expensive. The less the pool has of one asset, the more expensive it is to buy that asset.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That does not seem correct. 
If someone buys 400 Token there will be 1666,66 USDC and 600 Token left.
If they sell 400 Token there will be 1000 1000 again.
After that, there aren't any tokens left to sell.
So how can the value beneath 1USDC? Or in other words, how could I lose any money if I am providing 100% of enitre liquidity. 
Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why there wouldn't be any tokens left to sell, if both assets are back to 1000 again. It's like the two trades never occurred.

Comment: In order to sell an asset, you would need to own it. So if I hold 100% of the asset again there is nobody there who owns any to sell it? Or?

Comment: This is not related to what percentage of the asset you own from the asset's total supply. The only thing that matters is how much there is in the pool - the pool doesn't care how many assets are outside the pool

Comment: Logically it should. If I own 100% of the asset, nobody else can have any. Therefore they cant sell any. How do you want to sell something you don't own?